# Is there a way to query a ranged Expression in DB?

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

Our application is a Mainframe which is a IBM iSeries – DB2 database set up. Some of our table values have a range.

> Ex: 100;105;108;**110:160**;180

**-- UPDATE --**

The above data is from a single row (Single column to be precise). In the same format there would be multiple values (on various rows)

It this case, individual values are delimited by a “;” but 110:160 is a range. It includes all the values from 110 to 160. Now, for the individual values we were using like statements obviously. Ex; if I have to query for 105. 
The challenge here is, if **I had to query 125** which is technically not present in the database. However, logically I need to retrieve that record.

The system (application) somehow was able to accomplish this, I am not sure how. I am not a mainframe developer, I just had to query the database to retrieve a specific record for some of the automation that we work on.

As a workaround, I could think of two things:

- Expand the ranges and store it in a temp database programmatically.
  Ex: 110:160 would be expanded to 110;111;112..160 (Yes, it’s tedious)
- Reduce the number of records, by filtering through certain unique colums (the one’w which are without ranges) then programmatically apply a logic to identify the right record

As both are workarounds, I was so curious to how the system does it. (I reached out to dev’s of the app. So far, no luck). So is there a direct approach to achieve this ? Could it be a stored procedure ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i got your question right your example values are not in a single row but in multiple - otherwise some preprocessing has to be done.
I would destruct the combined value into its components with SQL - like:

```
with temp(id, text, value1, value2) as (
select id, text
      ,case when posstr(id,':') > 0 
            then substr(id, 1, posstr(id,':') - 1)
            else id
       end as value1
      ,case when posstr(id,':') > 0 
            then substr(id, posstr(id,':')+1 , length(id)) 
            else id
       end as value2
from testrange
)
select * from temp 
 where 125 between value1 and value2
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the data above is in a single Row. Also, would mind explaining the answer a bit ?

Comment: the common table expression (temp) selects the base table (here testrange) and has an ID column with i.e. '100:160' so it extracts everything before teh separatir (here ':') into column value1 and everything behind the ':' into column value2. So in the end it  could beselected from the temp table with a between WHERE condition. For single (no range)values -  value1 and  value2 contain just the single number

Comment: Can you have multiple ranges in a single row (beside a range an multiple single values)?

Comment: Yes, There could be multiple ranges as well. Ex: 120;125;130:145;150;160:165;180 (all these values in a single column).. In this case I naturally assume I need to split it dynamically ? based on the number of ranges (or No of occurrences of ":" in this case) ... Feels like we are getting somewhere hence up voted the answer

Comment: Yes a dynamic split is necessary and lead to recursive SQL - a good example is here: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/db2/6751/parse-comma-separated-values-in-a-column-into-multiple-rows#t=201705011436505870796   or via function like in the Blog from Knut Stolze https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0303stolze/0303stolze1.html

Comment: My database is iSeries/DB2. I think, should be able to work up my way from what you have given! Thanks! :)